# Angular Expression: Possibility to do type safe "or" ||

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS Views, I like to use expressions like

```
{{myScopeVariable || defaultText}}
```

However, if myScopeVariable is "0", defaultText is shown. 
Is there any way to evaluate the first part of the expression typesafe?

I would expect the following behaviour:

```
if myScopeVariable is 'undefined'
--> defaultText is shown

if myScopeVariable is 2
---> myScopeVariable is shown

if myScopeVariable is 0
---> myScopeVariable is shown (currently not the case)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use typeOf to check the data type.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help, as AngularJS expressions are  ["forgiving"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) -> if myScopeVariable is an Object property and the object is not defined yet, I'd have to do type checks all along the path of the property.

Comment: If possible create fiddle link..

Comment: I would recommend a filter at the least.  Javascript's boolean conversion is too... "weak" for this. `"0" || "hello" => "0"`, whereas `0 || "hello"` => "hello"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Phix commented I would go for the filter.

Actually there is a nice lib for some common filters that also includes a default-filter: https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-filters

(Here's the code for the default filter:
https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-filters/blob/develop/src/filters/default/default.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the library does exactly what I am searching for!